# Complicated usage of qualified-id refering to a template entity

Tags: c++, c++11

According to ISO/IEC 14882:2011(§5.1.1.8), *qualified-id* and *nested-name-specifier* are defined as below.

```
qualified-id:
    nested-name-specifier template(optional) unqualified-id
    ...

nested-name-specifier:
    ...
    nested-name-specifier template(optional) simple-template-id ::
```

Since i'm not familiar with the template, it is hard to imagine how the two nodes above, one for *qualified-id* and the other for *nested-name-specifier*, are nested. In other words, I can't easily come up with specific context on which combination of these two are used. **It would be great if you give me some examples which make use of *qualified-id* the way i described.** Please note that i omitted other nodes because of their simplicity.

Comment: In `std::vector<int>::iterator` `std::vector<int>::` is a nested-name-specifier, which contains another nested-name-specifier `std::` and a simple-template-id `vector<int>`, does it make sense?

Comment: @n.m. It seems i'm confused because of template keyword. What is optional template keyword for? When do we use template keyword in  _nested-name-specifier_?

Comment: It's for member templates, like in `X<Y>::template Z<T>`.